# Extracting .zip blob from XML to file with python

Tags: python, xml, blob

I have a large XML file output from database with Blob fields for attached zip files.
Example (sorry for long text output, I've selected the shortest one):

```
<Attach><FileName>Protocols.zip</FileName><Type>zip</Type><Blob>UEsDBBQAAAAIAAEXolL0xX1/dggAAEEZAAA2AAAAj+Cu4q6qrqsgrqEgrq/gpaSlq6WtqKgg4+eg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</Blob></Attach>
```

I'm trying to extract zipped with python:

```
with open("file.zip", "wb") as f_zip:
    f_zip.write(base64.b64encode(my_blob.encode('utf-8')))
```

The file is created but trying to open it I get an error "Unable to expand "file.zip". It is in an unsupported format"

Comment: `my_blob` is already base64 encoded, so you need to `b64decode`.

Comment: Initially it resulted with "Error:Incorrect Padding" but quick search allowed to solve it with extra pads. Updated the question with final solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution suggested by Maurice and mitigating possible incorrect padding error:

```
with open("file2.zip", "wb") as f_zip:
    f_zip.write(base64.b64decode(my_blob+ "==="))
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer and removed SOLVED from the title, SO style :-)